# Joomla 4.x robot.txt doesn't work for google

Tags: joomla-4.x, googlebots

I use Joomla 4.x, then I inspect the google search console and it only has a index.php crawled but any links shown in index.html are ignored, not followed.

this is the original robot.txt right from Joomla installation

```
# If the Joomla site is installed within a folder
# eg www.example.com/joomla/ then the robots.txt file
# MUST be moved to the site root
# eg www.example.com/robots.txt
# AND the joomla folder name MUST be prefixed to all of the
# paths.
# eg the Disallow rule for the /administrator/ folder MUST
# be changed to read
# Disallow: /joomla/administrator/
#
# For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
# https://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /api/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /layouts/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /tmp/
```

I want google to crawl my website other than disallow URL, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In System > Global Configuration > Site make sure that under Metadata > Robots is set to "index,follow" in the dropdown.

Comment: I did set to INDEX FOLLOW, but doesn't work, is it related to .htacces ?, but I know nothing about .htacces

Comment: @dhanysaguntoro If you think it might be related to `.htaccess` then you should update your question with the contents of your `.htaccess` file. However, there is nothing _normally_ in `.htaccess` that would affect crawling.

Comment: I created a new Folder inside Joomla Installation, the Files within this new folder are indexed normally by Google, and the files I mention here are PHP FILES with SQLite as a database, while Joomla uses MySQL, is it possible that the Problem is with MySQL server?